# Updating SQL Error ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have this SQL statement to update column `aisle from  table itemloc_tmp` from `aisle from table itemloc_tbl` in SQLPLUS, and it keeps returning the error like in the topic.

Update:
This is sample data from `itemloc_tmp`

```
ITEM_ID       SID SEC AIS
------------- --- --- ---
0007AAAAAAAAA     AA3 12
0007BBBBBBBBB     BB2 13
0007CCCCCCCCC     CC8 11
```

This is sample from `itemloc_tbl`

```
ITEM_ID       SID SEC AIS
------------- --- --- ---
0007AAAAAAAAA
0007BBBBBBBBB     
0007CCCCCCCCC
```

This is the my sql statement

```
    UPDATE ct.itemloc_tbl t1 SET 
    t1.aisle = (SELECT t2.aisle FROM ct.itemloc_tmp t2 WHERE t2.item_id = t1.item_id)
    WHERE t1.item_id IN (SELECT t2.item_id FROM ct.itemloc_tmp t2 WHERE t2.item_id = t1.item_id)
```

So, I want to update `aisle` column from `itemloc_tmp` to `itemloc_tbl`, but the statement above does not work. Would anyone point out where I was wrong?

Comment: Your subquery is returning multiple results (as the error says) -- which value should it use to update the `aisle` column?  Sample data and expected results would be helpful.

Comment: Like the error says: `SELECT t2.aisle FROM ct.itemloc_tmp t2 WHERE t2.item_id = t1.item_id` returns more than one row. I guess `item_id` values are not unique?  Is that normal?

Comment: yeah, `item_id` and `aisle` are not unique. And, I am trying to find a way to update `aisle`. Since, sqlplus seems not to have join function

Comment: You'll need to be clearer about what you are trying to accomplish + provide sample data as commented above. I mean, the way your query is set up now, the error makes sense.  If the subquery returns more than row with potentially different `aisle` values, how is Oracle supposed to know which value to use for the update?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my post, so it could be more clear for what I have wanted. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can limit the rows being updated.  Here are two ways.  The first uses `rownum = 1`:

```
UPDATE ct.itemloc_tbl t1 SET 
    SET t1.aisle = (SELECT t2.aisle FROM ct.itemloc_tmp t2 WHERE t2.item_id = t1.item_id AND rownum = 1)
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ct.itemloc_tmp t2 WHERE t2.item_id = t1.item_id);
```

The second uses an aggregation function:

```
UPDATE ct.itemloc_tbl t1 SET 
    SET t1.aisle = (SELECT MAX(t2.aisle) FROM ct.itemloc_tmp t2 WHERE t2.item_id = t1.item_id)
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ct.itemloc_tmp t2 WHERE t2.item_id = t1.item_id);
```

Either of these fix the proximal cause of the error, which is the subquery returning more than one row.  However, you need to decide what you really want for the assignment.  If an "arbitrary" value is fine, then these work.

Comment: Thank you, and I have updated the sample data from database.